# Cannot get custom setting from cli php.ini

Tags: php

I am running a simple php script on command line, I have modified my php.ini in /etc/php5/cli and added the following

```
[foo]
foo.name   = john
```

However when I try to access it from my script it doesn't show, I do a `php -i | grep "foo"` and also see nothing, I edited a php setting for example short_open_tag and switched it off and checked it using `php -i | grep "short_open_tag"` and it worked fine. I have also done a phpinfo(); within my script, ran it and piped the output through grep and still no joy.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can just arbitrarily add your own settings to php.ini and then expect them to be available to your script -- they have to be settings that the compiled modules know about. You're probably better off using an environment variable via getenv() and putenv(). Or, save your settings in a different ini file and then parse it yourself with parse_ini_file().